# Magento: Display "Guest" when adding Customer Group filter to Order Grid

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

i've tried to add a column for Customer Group on Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid.
And was partially successful, the only issue i'am having atm is that the column is empty if the Order was done by an Guest Customer.

My code:

```
<?php
class MyNamespace_CustomizeGrids_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends                         Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareColumns() {
        $groups = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')
                    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', array('gt' => 0))
                    ->load()
                    ->toOptionHash();

        $groups[0] = "Guest";


        $this->addColumn('customer_group_id', array(
            'header'  => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer Group'),
            'width'   => '100',
            'index'   => 'customer_group_id',
            'type'    => 'options',
            'options' => $groups,
        ));

        $this->addColumnsOrder('customer_group_id', 'shipping_name');

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

As you can see i fixxed this issue through manipulating the $groups array.

My question is: Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Guest, in Magento, the `customer_group_id` is `0` (NOT LOGGED IN)

In your query, you are saying magento to get all the groups which are GREATER THAN 0 
`array('gt' => 0)`

You can fix this by using:

```
array('gteq' => 0) // GREATER THAN EQUAL TO 0
```

instead of

```
array('gt' => 0) // GREATER THAN 0
```

Comment: Argh >.< goddam, i should know what my own code is doing -.-'

Thank you, works like a charm :)